# Automate android multi flavour app build generation

Tags: android, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, android-build-flavors, android-buildconfig

I want to automate build generation[apk/aab] of my application which having multiple flavours assume I have at least 10 flavours. Since taking debug build or release build is time-consuming process I would like to automate or write a build script in Gradle file by reading the DEBUG/RELEASE configurations from a file. Please guide me to create build script in Gradle file.